# High volatile response time of API

Tags: java, performance, rest, optimization, time

I have an API written in Java and spring boot. Response time is very critical for the end users.
The average time of API is `< 1 sec`. The issue comes when `10%` of calls gives high response time `> 3 sec`. Here is the graph taken from Kibana-
[image: Time distribution by number of calls]

I checked JVM graphs, it looks consistent. No spike in CPU usage, memory or number of threads. API just makes 2-3 database calls, the size of response is almost fixed.
So any Idea, what can be the cause for this, and How can I make response time consistent?

Comment: I guess you need to break it further down down and find out where you are losing time, when you do. Then you can maybe get to the reason why.

Comment: If I'm honest, 1 second already seems like a lot of time.  It's hard to say without knowing more about your setup, and troubleshooting complex systems like this is probably outside of Stack Overflow's scope.

Comment: There are several ways you can begin to troubleshoot.  I would start with using a decent profiler on your application to find out where the hot spots are.

Comment: What kind of API did you code? In some cases, `Websocket` is a great alternative, because here, you have lower latenzy and you can decide for yourself which rate you want to perform your requests